# Python 3.3 - Trouble Aligning Buttons and Labels with tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having trouble aligning my buttons and labels in a python PONG game gui I created with tkinter.  I've searched for answers on how to do this but found nothing  that resolved my issue.

What I'm trying to do is make the buttons not all stack on top of each other.  I want the score for the left player aligned to the left of the screen, and the score for the right player aligned to the right of the screen, and to be able to understand how to move the other buttons where I want them.

Things I've tried:

```
anchor = "..."
justify = "..."
grid(row="...", column = "...")
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

I'm wondering if it has to do with my use of canvas and buttons together?

Here is my code for the full program:

```
#PONG Game

from tkinter import *
import random
#http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_anchors.htm
#Globals
ball_x1 = 480
ball_x2 = 520
ball_y1 = 280
ball_y2 = 320

left_paddle_x1 = 0
left_paddle_x2 = 20
left_paddle_y1 = 240
left_paddle_y2 = 360

right_paddle_x1 = 980
right_paddle_x2 = 1000
right_paddle_y1 = 240
right_paddle_y2 = 360

left_player_score = 0
right_player_score = 0

paused = False

ball_x_motion = 10#random.randrange(-20, 20) #actually need to make a set number but random direction
ball_y_motion = 10#random.randrange(-20, 20)

def start():
    global paused
    if(field.coords(ball)[0] == 480):
        paused = False
        ball_movement()
    else:
        new_game(False)


def pause():
    global paused
    if(paused):
        paused = False
    else:
        paused = True
    ball_movement()
def new_game(reset):        
    global ball_x1, ball_x2, ball_y1, ball_y2, left_paddle_x1, left_paddle_x2, left_paddle_y1, left_paddle_yw
    global right_paddle_x1, right_paddle_x2, right_paddle_y1, right_paddle_y2
    global paused, left_player_score, right_player_score
    print("here1")
    if(reset):
        left_player_score = 0
        right_player_score = 0
        print("here")
        left_player_score_label.config(text=left_player_score)
        right_player_score_label.config(text=right_player_score)

        left_paddle_x1 = 0
        left_paddle_x2 = 20
        left_paddle_y1 = 240
        left_paddle_y2 = 360

        right_paddle_x1 = 980
        right_paddle_x2 = 1000
        right_paddle_y1 = 240
        right_paddle_y2 = 360

        field.coords(left_paddle, left_paddle_x1,  left_paddle_y1, left_paddle_x2, left_paddle_y2)
        field.coords(right_paddle, right_paddle_x1,  right_paddle_y1, right_paddle_x2, right_paddle_y2)

        paused = True
    print("here2")
    #starting positions
    ball_x1 = 480
    ball_x2 = 520
    ball_y1 = 280
    ball_y2 = 320


    field.coords(ball, ball_x1, ball_y1, ball_x2, ball_y2)



#Event Handlers

def ball_movement():
    #while(variable = true) move ball
    # move the object
    global ball_x_motion, ball_y_motion, ball_x1, ball_x2, ball_y1, ball_y2, paused
    global left_player_score, right_player_score

        #keep ball on playing field horizontally if ball hits paddles

    print(((((left_paddle_y1 + left_paddle_y2)/2) - ((ball_y1 + ball_y2)/2))))
    if(((ball_x1 <= 20) and (-60 <= ((((left_paddle_y1 + left_paddle_y2)/2) - ((ball_y1 + ball_y2)/2))) <= 60)) or ((ball_x2 >= 980) and (-60 <= ((((right_paddle_y1 + right_paddle_y2)/2) - ((ball_y1 + ball_y2)/2))) <= 60))):
        ball_x_motion = -ball_x_motion
        #increase speed
    elif(ball_x1 <=0):
        right_player_score += 1
        new_game(False)
        #paused = True
        right_player_score_label.config(text=right_player_score)
    elif(ball_x2 >= 1000):
        left_player_score += 1
        new_game(False)
        #paused = True
        left_player_score_label.config(text=left_player_score)
    if(field.coords(ball)[1] <= 0 or field.coords(ball)[3] >= 600): #keep ball in playing field vertically
        ball_y_motion = -ball_y_motion
        #increase speed
    if(not paused):  
        field.coords(ball, ball_x1 + ball_x_motion, ball_y1 + ball_y_motion, ball_x2 + ball_x_motion, ball_y2 + ball_y_motion)

        ball_x1 = field.coords(ball)[0]
        ball_x2 = field.coords(ball)[2]
        ball_y1 = field.coords(ball)[1]
        ball_y2 = field.coords(ball)[3]


        #ball moves every 10 milliseconds    
        field.after(10, ball_movement)


def move_left_paddle_up(event):
    global left_paddle_y1, left_paddle_y2
    #print(event.keysym)
    if(field.coords(left_paddle)[1] > 0):
        field.move("left_paddle", 0, -40)
        left_paddle_y1 = field.coords(left_paddle)[1]
        left_paddle_y2 = field.coords(left_paddle)[3]

def move_left_paddle_down(event):
    global left_paddle_y1, left_paddle_y2
    if(field.coords(left_paddle)[3] < 600):
        field.move("left_paddle", 0, 40)
        left_paddle_y1 = field.coords(left_paddle)[1]
        left_paddle_y2 = field.coords(left_paddle)[3]


def move_right_paddle_up(event):
    global right_paddle_y1, right_paddle_y2
    if(field.coords(right_paddle)[1] > 0):
        field.move("right_paddle", 0, -40)
        right_paddle_y1 = field.coords(right_paddle)[1]
        right_paddle_y2 = field.coords(right_paddle)[3]
        #print(event.keysym)

def move_right_paddle_down(event):
    global right_paddle_y1, right_paddle_y2
    if(field.coords(right_paddle)[3] < 600):
        field.move("right_paddle", 0, 40)
        right_paddle_y1 = field.coords(right_paddle)[1]
        right_paddle_y2 = field.coords(right_paddle)[3]
    #print(event.keysym) 
#Canvas
master = Tk() #master
field = Canvas(master, width=1000, height=600, bg="black") #playing field

master.bind('<w>', move_left_paddle_up) #left paddle up
master.bind('<s>', move_left_paddle_down) #left paddle down
master.bind('<Up>', move_right_paddle_up) #right paddle up
master.bind('<Down>', move_right_paddle_down) #right paddle down


#create field border lines with a rectangle
border = field.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 600, fill="gray")

#create midline
midline = field.create_line(500, 0, 500, 600, fill="white", dash=(4, 4))

#create ball      
ball = field.create_oval(ball_x1, ball_y1, ball_x2, ball_y2, fill="white", tags=("ball"))


#create left paddle
left_paddle = field.create_rectangle(left_paddle_x1, left_paddle_y1, left_paddle_x2, left_paddle_y2, fill="red", tags=("left_paddle"))

#create right paddle
right_paddle = field.create_rectangle(right_paddle_x1, right_paddle_y1, right_paddle_x2, right_paddle_y2, fill="blue", tags=("right_paddle"))

#create Pause Button
pause_button = Button(master, text="Pause/Unpause", command=pause)
#pause_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
pause_button.pack()



#create Start Button
start_button = Button(master, text="Start", command=start)
#start_button.grid(row=1, column=3)
start_button.pack()

#left player scorekeeper
left_player_score_label = Label(master, text=left_player_score)
left_player_score_label.pack()

#right player scorekeeper
right_player_score_label = Label(master, text=right_player_score)
right_player_score_label.pack()

#create New Game Button
new_game_button = Button(master, text="New Game", command=lambda: new_game(True))
#new_game_button.grid(row=1, column=2)
new_game_button.pack()

#pack it all together on the screen
field.pack()

#execute loop to run screen processing
mainloop()
```

**Edit**

This is the final result after changing from pack() to grid().  I realized that you don't use both, but rather one or the other.

```
#PONG Game

from tkinter import *
import random
#http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_anchors.htm
#Globals
ball_x1 = 480
ball_x2 = 520
ball_y1 = 280
ball_y2 = 320

left_paddle_x1 = 0
left_paddle_x2 = 20
left_paddle_y1 = 240
left_paddle_y2 = 360

right_paddle_x1 = 980
right_paddle_x2 = 1000
right_paddle_y1 = 240
right_paddle_y2 = 360

left_player_score = 0
right_player_score = 0

paused = False
direction_factor = random.randrange(0,1)
ball_x_motion = 5
ball_y_motion = random.randrange(-5, 5)
if direction_factor == 0:
    ball_x_motion *= -1

def start():
    global paused
    if(field.coords(ball)[0] == 480):
        paused = False
        ball_movement()
    else:
        new_game(False)


def pause():
    global paused
    if(paused):
        paused = False
    else:
        paused = True
    ball_movement()
def new_game(reset):        
    global ball_x1, ball_x2, ball_y1, ball_y2, left_paddle_x1, left_paddle_x2, left_paddle_y1, left_paddle_yw
    global right_paddle_x1, right_paddle_x2, right_paddle_y1, right_paddle_y2
    global paused, left_player_score, right_player_score, ball_x_motion, ball_y_motion, direction_factor


    direction_factor = random.randrange(0,1)
    ball_x_motion = 10
    ball_y_motion = random.randrange(-10, 10)
    if direction_factor == 0:
        ball_x_motion *= -1 
    if(reset):
        left_player_score = 0
        right_player_score = 0

        left_player_score_label.config(text=left_player_score)
        right_player_score_label.config(text=right_player_score)

        left_paddle_x1 = 0
        left_paddle_x2 = 20
        left_paddle_y1 = 240
        left_paddle_y2 = 360

        right_paddle_x1 = 980
        right_paddle_x2 = 1000
        right_paddle_y1 = 240
        right_paddle_y2 = 360

        field.coords(left_paddle, left_paddle_x1,  left_paddle_y1, left_paddle_x2, left_paddle_y2)
        field.coords(right_paddle, right_paddle_x1,  right_paddle_y1, right_paddle_x2, right_paddle_y2)

        paused = True

    #starting positions
    ball_x1 = 480
    ball_x2 = 520
    ball_y1 = 280
    ball_y2 = 320


    field.coords(ball, ball_x1, ball_y1, ball_x2, ball_y2)



#Event Handlers

def ball_movement():
    #while(variable = true) move ball
    # move the object
    global ball_x_motion, ball_y_motion, ball_x1, ball_x2, ball_y1, ball_y2, paused
    global left_player_score, right_player_score

        #keep ball on playing field horizontally if ball hits paddles

    #print(((((left_paddle_y1 + left_paddle_y2)/2) - ((ball_y1 + ball_y2)/2))))
    if(((ball_x1 <= 20) and (-60 <= ((((left_paddle_y1 + left_paddle_y2)/2) - ((ball_y1 + ball_y2)/2))) <= 60)) or ((ball_x2 >= 980) and (-60 <= ((((right_paddle_y1 + right_paddle_y2)/2) - ((ball_y1 + ball_y2)/2))) <= 60))):
        ball_x_motion *= -1.1
        #ball_y_motion = ball_y_motion + 5
    elif(ball_x1 <=0):
        right_player_score += 1
        new_game(False)
        #paused = True
        right_player_score_label.config(text=right_player_score)
    elif(ball_x2 >= 1000):
        left_player_score += 1
        new_game(False)
        #paused = True
        left_player_score_label.config(text=left_player_score)
    if(field.coords(ball)[1] <= 0 or field.coords(ball)[3] >= 600): #keep ball in playing field vertically
        ball_y_motion = -ball_y_motion
    if(not paused):  
        field.coords(ball, ball_x1 + ball_x_motion, ball_y1 + ball_y_motion, ball_x2 + ball_x_motion, ball_y2 + ball_y_motion)

        ball_x1 = field.coords(ball)[0]
        ball_x2 = field.coords(ball)[2]
        ball_y1 = field.coords(ball)[1]
        ball_y2 = field.coords(ball)[3]


        #ball moves every 10 milliseconds    
        field.after(10, ball_movement)


def move_left_paddle_up(event):
    global left_paddle_y1, left_paddle_y2
    #print(event.keysym)
    if(field.coords(left_paddle)[1] > 0):
        field.move("left_paddle", 0, -40)
        left_paddle_y1 = field.coords(left_paddle)[1]
        left_paddle_y2 = field.coords(left_paddle)[3]

def move_left_paddle_down(event):
    global left_paddle_y1, left_paddle_y2
    if(field.coords(left_paddle)[3] < 600):
        field.move("left_paddle", 0, 40)
        left_paddle_y1 = field.coords(left_paddle)[1]
        left_paddle_y2 = field.coords(left_paddle)[3]


def move_right_paddle_up(event):
    global right_paddle_y1, right_paddle_y2
    if(field.coords(right_paddle)[1] > 0):
        field.move("right_paddle", 0, -40)
        right_paddle_y1 = field.coords(right_paddle)[1]
        right_paddle_y2 = field.coords(right_paddle)[3]
        #print(event.keysym)

def move_right_paddle_down(event):
    global right_paddle_y1, right_paddle_y2
    if(field.coords(right_paddle)[3] < 600):
        field.move("right_paddle", 0, 40)
        right_paddle_y1 = field.coords(right_paddle)[1]
        right_paddle_y2 = field.coords(right_paddle)[3]
    #print(event.keysym) 
#Canvas
master = Tk() #master
field = Canvas(master, width=1000, height=600, bg="black") #playing field
field.grid(row=4, columnspan=10)
#field.pack()

master.bind('<w>', move_left_paddle_up) #left paddle up
master.bind('<s>', move_left_paddle_down) #left paddle down
master.bind('<Up>', move_right_paddle_up) #right paddle up
master.bind('<Down>', move_right_paddle_down) #right paddle down


#create field border lines with a rectangle
border = field.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 600, fill="gray")

#create midline
midline = field.create_line(500, 0, 500, 600, fill="white", dash=(4, 4))

#create ball      
ball = field.create_oval(ball_x1, ball_y1, ball_x2, ball_y2, fill="white", tags=("ball"))


#create left paddle
left_paddle = field.create_rectangle(left_paddle_x1, left_paddle_y1, left_paddle_x2, left_paddle_y2, fill="red", tags=("left_paddle"))

#create right paddle
right_paddle = field.create_rectangle(right_paddle_x1, right_paddle_y1, right_paddle_x2, right_paddle_y2, fill="blue", tags=("right_paddle"))

#create Pause Button
pause_button = Button(master, text="Pause/Unpause", command=pause)
pause_button.grid(row=1, column=6)
#pause_button.pack()



#create Start Button
start_button = Button(master, text="Start", command=start)
start_button.grid(row=1, column=4)
#start_button.pack()

#left player scorekeeper
left_player_score_label = Label(master, text=left_player_score)
left_player_score_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
#left_player_score_label.pack()

#right player scorekeeper
right_player_score_label = Label(master, text=right_player_score)
right_player_score_label.grid(row=1, column=9)
#right_player_score_label.pack()

#create New Game Button
new_game_button = Button(master, text="New Game", command=lambda: new_game(True))
new_game_button.grid(row=1, column=5)
#new_game_button.pack()

#pack it all together on the screen
#field.pack()

#execute loop to run screen processing
mainloop()
```

Comment: Think of it like this: `master` is the main window. You pack the canvas in, and you pack the buttons and labels in. Where they go is up to you. Start here: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-geometry.htm

Comment: I didn't find that comment very helpful, it was pretty vague, but it did get me thinking more about it and I realized that you don't use both the grid manager and the pack manager, it's one or the other.  So I deleted the `pack()`'s that I had and used all `grid()`'s.  Here's the result:

Comment: My apologies. You seem to have it working now; I did have an answer halfway typed, but then I felt like it was getting too lengthy and just reiterating everything on the page that I linked, so I just chose to leave the link as a comment instead. Anyway, good luck on the rest of your project!

Comment: @user3533772: you can use both grid and pack in the same app, you just can't use them both on widgets that share the same parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that you don't use both the grid manager and the pack manager, it's one or the other. So I deleted the pack()'s that I had and used all grid()'s and posted the final result.

Comment: you can use both grid and pack in the same app, you just can't use them both on widgets that share the same parent.